# Stub request in a Rails gem with persistent HTTPClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

I'm trying to write an RSpec test that stubs out requests to api.box.com using the Boxr gem (https://github.com/cburnette/boxr). I've created a stub that goes to a fake Box class using the #to_rack method

```
stub_request(:any, %r{^https?://api.box.com}).to_rack(FakeBox)
```

and my FakeBox class:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class FakeBox < Sinatra::Base
  post /oauth2/ do
    debugger
    content_type :json
    status 200
    '{ "access_token": "<some_token>", "expires_in": 3979, "restricted_to": [],' +
     '"refresh_token": "<some_refresh>",' +
     '"token_type": "bearer" }'
  end
end
```

This fake is triggered anytime I call `Net::HTTP.get('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token')` or `HTTPClient.new.post(...)` directly in the controller or in the test method.

However, it is not triggered when I call `Boxr::get_tokens(params[:code])`
I put a debugger in the Boxr gem itself:

```
def self.auth_post(uri, body)
    uri = Addressable::URI.encode(uri)

    res = BOX_CLIENT.post(uri, body: body)
    debugger

    if(res.status==200)
      body_json = Oj.load(res.body)
      return BoxrMash.new(body_json)
    else
      raise BoxrError.new(status: res.status, body: res.body, header: res.header)
    end
  end
```

BOX_CLIENT is defined here:

```
module Boxr
  Oj.default_options = {:mode => :compat }

  #The root folder in Box is always identified by 0
  ROOT = 0

  #HTTPClient is high-performance, thread-safe, and supports persistent HTTPS connections
  #http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/ruby-http-performance-shootout-redux/
  BOX_CLIENT = HTTPClient.new
  BOX_CLIENT.cookie_manager = nil
  BOX_CLIENT.send_timeout = 3600 #one hour; needed for lengthy uploads
  BOX_CLIENT.agent_name = "Boxr/#{Boxr::VERSION}"
  BOX_CLIENT.transparent_gzip_decompression = true 
  #BOX_CLIENT.ssl_config.add_trust_ca("/Users/cburnette/code/ssh-keys/dev_root_ca.pem")

  def self.turn_on_debugging(device=STDOUT)
    BOX_CLIENT.debug_dev = device
    BOX_CLIENT.transparent_gzip_decompression = false
    nil
  end

  def self.turn_off_debugging
    BOX_CLIENT.debug_dev = nil
    BOX_CLIENT.transparent_gzip_decompression = true
    nil
  end
end
```

When the debugger is triggered, the response I get shows that the `BOX_CLIENT.post(uri, body: body)` visited the site and got back an error when I expected it to trigger the mock. In the debug console at that breakpoint, I entered `HTTPClient.new.post(uri, body: body)` and I got the stubbed response that I was expecting.

When I entered `HTTPClient.new.class` in the debugger console I got: WebMockHTTPClient. `BOX_CLIENT.class` -> HTTPClient. This seems to be the source of my problem.

I can't modify the gem. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: My guess is that BOX_CLIENT is being defined before the stub_request method is called, so maybe I need to figure out how to either load the gem later in the setup pipeline or call the stub earlier?

Answer (score -1):

Just had to remove `require: false` from `gem 'webmock', require: false` in the Gemfile